# How can I restore the registry keys from another C drive on Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, boot, bios, windows-registry

I ran Uniblue registry booster on my system which was working fine. It did a full back up of the registry keys. Now I cannot boot from that disk. I also cannot get into the BIOS!

To restore the registry I have to run Uniblue registry booster from **within** Windows. I cannot get there.

I can boot up on another C drive, and can see the files on the drive with the problem.
Is there any way I can find the Registry Booster backup files and restore it from the other disk? Or find the registry backup and upload it into the registry so I can boot off the other disk again?

Or, Can I do a Windows repair from the other disk? NB: not getting in to the bios means I cannot boot off the CD/DVD!  (I can use the DVD drive from within Windows)

Any ideas? I do not want to reinstall everything yet again, it takes about 6 hours.

Comment: You BIOS has nothing to do with the registry. Are you sure you do not have two separate problems?

Answer (score 1):

It goes without saying that you should back up all your user data first and anything important on the *broken* machine.  As you should be aware, there are risks in doing this, and really the easiest thing would be a full install - and to not mess with the registry.  But, that of course is up to you. However, you may see latent issues if/when you get Windows back up...

Here is a pretty good guide, I used it once when I was in IT (though that was a while ago).

You should be able to load the other drive's Hive file and restore that way:

> [EHOW Run-Through](http://www.ehow.com/how_7627161_repair-registry-different-drive.html)
>
> 1. Login to your other Windows drive
> 2. Type "regedit.exe" into the search box
> 3. Expand "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE", click "FILE" > "Load Hive", navigate to your broken drive.
> 4. Browse to "Windows\System32\Config", select a Hive file from the list (SAM/Security = User Rights / Passwords, System = OS,
>      Software = third party)
> 5. Click "Open" and name it, click OK
> 6. Modify away, though this will be pretty manual.
> 7. Left click Hive, "File" > "Unload Hive"

Answer (score 0):

There are tools to delete BIOS password !

A. The best way of acting would be to do a system restore if there are RestorePoints. Boot from external media (USB/CD/DVD) go to Recovery and see if restore can be done.

B. If you have a full backup of system would also help doing a full restore.

In case you cannot use A. or B. -

1. Boot to another OS.
2. Replace system registry files for demagged OS in \Windows\System32\config:

DEFAULT, SAM, SECURITY, SOFTWARE, SYSTEM

with same files from \Windows\System32\config\RegBack

(or the registry backup files made by Uniblue - you can do a search for "DEFAULT" on demagged drive).

Simple file delete and copy operation.

---

**DO NOT USE REGISTRY TOOLS - THEY CAN DO MORE HARM THAN GOOD !**

In newer versions of Windows registry is handled pretty well and there is no need optimizing it.